# pg_stat_statements and pg_stat_activity doesn't show comment in SQL starts with --

Tags: postgresql

### Background

- My application uses PostgreSQL as DB.
- In my application, there are many SQLs that start with similar clauses (for example, start with the same and long `WITH` clause and end with a different `SELECT` statement).
- When I investigate problems in SQL, I frequently use the result `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_stat_activity`.
- The `query` column of `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_stat_activity` only shows the first 1024 bytes of SQLs, so it is impossible to distinguish two or more SQLs starting with the same and long `WITH` clause. To solve this problem, I have tried to add a comment with the ID of SQL like `-- SQL ID: 1`.

Note that you can change the `track_activity_query_size` parameter, but you will have a lot of trouble with distinguishing similar SQLs.

### Problem

`pg_stat_statements` and `pg_stat_activity` don't show the `-- comment` style comment on the `query` column.
On the other hand, the `/* comment */` style comment is shown in the `query` column.

```
postgres=# /* comment 1 */ SELECT pg_sleep(1);
 ...
postgres=# /* comment 2 */
SELECT pg_sleep(1), pg_sleep(1);
 ...
postgres=# -- comment 3
postgres=# select pg_sleep(1), pg_sleep(1), pg_sleep(1);
 ...
postgres=# SELECT query FROM pg_stat_statements;
                        query                         
------------------------------------------------------
 select pg_sleep($1), pg_sleep($2), pg_sleep($3)
 /* comment 2 */                                     +
 SELECT pg_sleep($1), pg_sleep($2)
 /* comment 1 */ SELECT pg_sleep($1)
 /* comment 1 */ SELECT query FROM pg_stat_statements
(4 rows)
```

```
postgres=# /* comment 1 */ SELECT pg_sleep(100);
 ...
postgres=# /* comment 2 */
postgres-# SELECT pg_sleep(200);
 ...
postgres=# -- comment 3
postgres=# SELECT pg_sleep(300);
 ...
postgres=# SELECT pid, query FROM pg_stat_activity;
 pid |                  query                   
-----+------------------------------------------
 150 | 
 152 | 
 166 | SELECT pid, query FROM pg_stat_activity;
 188 | /* comment 1 */ SELECT pg_sleep(100);
 208 | /* comment 2 */                         +
     | SELECT pg_sleep(200);
 222 | SELECT pg_sleep(300);
 148 | 
 147 | 
 149 | 
(9 rows)
```

### Query

Is there any way to show a `-- comment` style comment on the result of `pg_stat_statements` and `pg_stat_activity`?

Or do I have to change the comment on my SQL to `/* comment */` style ones?

Comment: In your first CTE, add something like `'query 1' as querytag` at the beginning of the select list.  As long as subsequent CTEs and queries are not doing any `select *` queries, this should have zero impact on your existing queries and will allow you to identify the query from pg_stat_activity.

Comment: Whether the client transmits the comment to the server is up to the client.  If the comment does get sent, the server will record it.  You haven't indicated your client.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you for your advice. I never knew it depended on the client. My application is written in Java and uses MyBatis to execute SQL, so I guess I have to see the behavior with MyBatis ...

Comment: I have the same problem with python & psycopg. I've not tested the `/* */` style yet. Nor have I dug into the client source or attempted to reproduce with psql on the command line. I shall report back if I find something of note.